Dynamic Date Filter/Parameter Tableau
I have a dashboard that shows total sales for a day as well as revenue.  I have a filter on that dashboard that allows me to go between days and see sales for a specific day (not every day of the year is in this filter).  I want the filter to automatically go to today or the next closest day in the future when I publish it, while still allowing users to filter between days as they like.  For example today is "7/11/24" let's say there are no sales today but we have them for "7/14/24" and that's the next day where sales show up.  That should be the default date when users open the dashboard online.  For those who are wondering and would like some clarification why we would look at future sales, I work in live events so this is essentially looking at sales for an upcoming event and tracking that.
I tried creating a calculated field to find the next closest event then having a dashboard action dynamically default to that field but it didn't work.

Default your filter or dashboard (do so by publishing the dashboard) to use the MAX function on the column you're pulling your sales date from.
So: MAX([sales date])
If you are using a calculated field and parameter combo, you can use a parameter to drive how users interact with your calculated field date filter. So they can cut it any way they'd like, and it also allows you to default to, in this case the most recent or future date, and any other date or date range you'd like.
